# Text not appearing beside CheckBox android

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view_Maint_RecyclerView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_custom_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.54"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_Maint_Fail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/SpMainFail"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="FailureType"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/accent"/>

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Maint_Modules"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/SpMaintModules"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="Module"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/accent"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Maint_Problems"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/SpMaintProblems"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="Problem"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/accent" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Maint_Symptom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/SpMaintSymptom"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="Symptom"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/accent"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Maint_Resolution"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/SpMaintResolutions"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="Resolution"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/accent"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/SpMaintStatus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <CheckBox

                    android:id="@+id/cbProductdown_"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:theme = "@style/CheckBoxTheme"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPeriodText_"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Product_Down"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Maint_ok"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/OK"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomButtonStyle"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_Maint_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="@string/Cancel"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:theme="@style/CustomButtonStyle"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: This is my dialog]
[image: The Text <code>product down</code> is moving to end when trying to fill remaining fields.]
[image: Some times It will disappear]

This is check box theme

```
<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Lightaccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

The Text `product down` is moving to end. At start it will be at the correct position but when start filling fields from the start, automatically text view is moving to right side. I am using Relative layout here.

I have added complete code of my layout. Some times it will disappear.

What might be the problem? Please Help Me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No need of Relative layout here. Also please remove the android:layout_gravity="center" from the CardView. Also  remove android:layout_weight="0.54"

Comment: post your `@style/CheckBoxTheme`

Comment: I have posted the @style/CheckBoxTheme code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of your theme `@style/CheckBoxTheme`

- Removing the theme might solve your problem.  **OR,**
- Add `android:text` attribute to your `CheckBox` widget like this:-

  ```
          <CheckBox
              android:id="@+id/cbProductdown_"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              ....
              ....
              ....
              android:text="Product"
              />
  ```

  *Instead* of adding a **TextView Widget** beside **CheckBox** you can directly *assign* text to your checkbox ( `android:text="Product"` )

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Thanks a lot.@Santanu Sur